# Heightmap VS actual model of environment

Tags: 3d, game-design, models, heightmap

I've been looking at 3D environments for games and I would like to know (case by case) which would be the best fit for development. The types in question are between **heightmaps** or a **model of an environment** (created in Maya, Max, etc). And when I say "environment," I mean "the ground the player walks on (street, hill, valley, etc).

Here are the scenarios based off of actual games:

1. **Red Dead Redemption** - massive open world
2. **Gears of War** - smaller/confined world and linear navigation; urban + natural
3. **MW3** - small world; urban-oriented

Which is the best fit for developing the ground for each of these games?

*Keep in mind that these games have varying degrees of slopes.*

**Update**

1. This is not a coding problem. This is a design problem.
2. I'm not asking how the above games were codes. I'm asking about the environment "style of whether it would be best to use a height map or model the environment (terrain) entirely within a 3D editor.

Comment: So... Is this an actual problem you're facing? Sounds like you just want a discussion. I don't see how an answer to this could help you in your own development.

Comment: I really doubt any of these games use heightmaps.

Comment: @Byte56 If you dont understand the question, move on and let someone else who does understand a chance to answer the question instead of downvoting. This is a scenario-based problem. Not a "why cant I..."-based problem.

Comment: @Almo It's not so much these games, but how these game's environments are built.

Comment: @ChocoMan I'm glad you can be civil about it. Someone still has the chance to answer the question. The voting buttons are there for people to express their opinion of the quality of the question. I'm using them as I'm supposed to. It's not personal. I understand what you're asking. I don't understand how it can fit within the rules of the site. Perhaps you can explain that?

Comment: I agree with @Byte56,  as it stands this question is not a good fit for this Q&A site, voting to close too. However, feel free to rephrase the question with an actual implementation problem of your game project that you are facing, which is answerable.

Comment: @MaikSemder Oh so you are just looking for code. This is not a coding problem, so if you are looking for free code, go to github.

Comment: @ChocoMan You think Maik is trying to scam some free code off of you? He's trying to **help** you improve your question. Relax and take a second look at what's really going on.

Comment: @Byte56 the question is updated

Comment: the update doesn't help

Comment: @ChocoMan Don't forget the "relax" part. Updating the question with all caps is not going to make it better. To avoid further trouble, I direct you to the [FAQ]. You can find some sites listed there that are more open to discussion oriented questions. You should ask this question there. You've re-clarified the question I think everyone understood. You haven't told us how it fits in with the constructive style that questions on this site should have.

Comment: @Jimmy How would you model these types of environments? Height maps with assets, or all within a 3D editor? Thats the question

Comment: @Byte56 Would you please stop bullying my post and let someone else that understands answer it?

Comment: @ChocoMan Sorry if you think I was doing that. I was trying to help you from getting the question closed is all. I'll let this question take its course without further input from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most games (I guess all you listed) combine both approaches to reduce the amount of data to process and render.

Using one huge model is very costly, because you'll always have to draw everything (or do lots of culling calculations).

Due to this, the probably most often used approach is drawing the raw map using one or more heightmaps (to improve performance, you'd most likely split this into "cells").

In addition, these cells are decorated with more detailed and modeled objects, such as rocks, cliffs, bridges, houses, etc.

When drawing, you can then restrict yourself to only draw the heightmap of the current (or neighboring) cells as well as all their objects. Recent and popular examples would be games such as Skyrim or Far Cry 3.

This approach will be less attractive if you plan on doing things like indoor maps. Brush based drawing, e.g. as done by Valve's Source engine are more suited for something like this. Overall they'll still do the same thing: Use the rough drawing (brushes here) to create the map, objects to decorate it.

So in short: Always try to get your general map layout done with some simple method. Keep this simple, because this will be fast and allow you to cull other elements (e.g. using depth buffers, cell hierarchy, etc.). Then add the details.